# Probability that a series of guesses from a normal distribution are non-random

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random-variable

Let's say I'm playing a game with my friends on the internet in which I guess their height. Furthermore, let's assume that the height in this population is normally distributed. At the end of this experiment, they each tell me their true heights. How would I go about calculating if my guesses were better than random?

My thoughts so far: I could calculate the mean and standard deviation of the given heights in the population. Then, I might find the critical values corresponding to better-than-random guessing:

`qnorm(0.25,mean=μ,sd=σ)` and `qnorm(0.75,mean=μ,sd=σ)`

Then, I would calculate the average of my guesses and see if it falls within these critical values.

Where I'm getting stuck: it seems this way of addressing the question only answers whether the overall average of my guesses differs from the overall average of the true values. It seems that for this calculation I should somehow take into account my error for each person individually, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks for reading my question, I look forward to learning something!